# Automate Removal of a Path System Environment Variable

Tags: powershell

I'm running into an issue where a removal and reinstallation of a particular application is creating duplicate entries in System Variables under Path. So for example, it's showing `C:\Apps\folder;C:\Apps\folder;typical` entries.

While this is not causing a problem with functionality of the app, I'd prefer to not have the entry in there twice (or more if it requires an additional removal/installation). I want to automate something so I don't have to go into each system and manually remove one of those entries.

Can this be done through either a batch file or a PowerShell script? I'm not able to find a way, but hopefully someone here will know a way. It's fine if the method removes both entries, as I can add something to the script to add one of them back.  One important note, I need to make sure everything else under Path is left intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script (taken from a Microsoft repository) that I used to do the exact same thing.

```
$RegKey = ([Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine).OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment", $True)
$PathValue = $RegKey.GetValue("Path", $Null, "DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames")
Write-host "Original path :" + $PathValue
$PathValues = $PathValue.Split(";", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
$IsDuplicate = $False
$NewValues = @()

ForEach ($Value in $PathValues)
{
    if ($NewValues -notcontains $Value)
    {
        $NewValues += $Value
    }
    else
    {
        $IsDuplicate = $True
    }
}

if ($IsDuplicate)
{
    $NewValue = $NewValues -join ";"
    $RegKey.SetValue("Path", $NewValue, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::ExpandString)
    Write-Host "Duplicate PATH entry found and new PATH built removing all duplicates. New Path :" + $NewValue
}
else
{
    Write-Host "No Duplicate PATH entries found. The PATH will remain the same."
}

$RegKey.Close()
```